# Reordenação de Lista com Base na Entrado do Usuário

Tags: javascript, html

Fala pessoal, estou tentando desenvolver uma lista dinâmica que tenha uma coluna chamada ORDEM, essa coluna é editável, se o usuário alterar a coluna ordem, todos os itens da tabela devem ser reordenadas com base na  entrada do usuário. Eu consegui fazer isso:

```
    <table id="order-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Ordem</th>
        <th>Item</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" value="1" class="order-input"></td>
        <td>Item 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" value="2" class="order-input"></td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" value="3" class="order-input"></td>
        <td>Item 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <script>
    const table = document.getElementById("order-table");
const inputs = table.getElementsByClassName("order-input");

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
    const newOrder = this.value;
    const currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;

    // Verificar se há duplicatas na ordem
    let duplicate = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
      if (inputs[j].value === newOrder && inputs[j] !== this) {
        duplicate = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    // Substituir a posição existente, se houver
    if (duplicate) {
      for (let j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
        if (inputs[j].value === newOrder && inputs[j] !== this) {
          inputs[j].value = this.defaultValue;
          break;
        }
      }
      this.defaultValue = newOrder;
    }

    // Reordenar a lista
    const rows = [...table.getElementsByTagName("tr")].slice(1);
    rows.sort((a, b) => a.getElementsByClassName("order-input")[0].value - b.getElementsByClassName("order-input")[0].value);
    rows.forEach(row => table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].appendChild(row));
  });
}
  </script>
```

De certa forma funciona, mas se eu tenho uma lista do tipo: item A ordem 1 - Item B ordem 2 - Item C ordem 3 e eu defino ordem 3 para o item A, ele somente substitui o item C pelo item A, eu preciso que a lista reordene por exemplo: Se eu mudar o item A para ordem 3, o item B deve se tornar a primeira, o item c a segunda e por fim o item a o ultimo, como posso fazer?

Answer (score -2):

Podes usar a função sort para definir o que acontece para cada caso e no final renomeias todos os valores para a sua posição na tabela.

```
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
    const newOrder = this.value;
    const currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;

    // Reordenar a lista
    const rows = [...table.getElementsByTagName("tr")].slice(1);
    rows.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.getElementsByClassName("order-input")[0].value === b.getElementsByClassName("order-input")[0].value) {
          return 1;
      }

      if (a.getElementsByClassName("order-input")[0].value < b.getElementsByClassName("order-input")[0].value) {
          return 0;
      }

      if (a.getElementsByClassName("order-input")[0].value > b.getElementsByClassName("order-input")[0].value) {
          return 1;
      }

      return 0;
    });

    // Renomear os valores
    rows.forEach((row, index) => {
      row.getElementsByClassName("order-input")[0].value = index + 1;
    });
    rows.forEach(row => table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].appendChild(row));
  });
}
```